# Errors with SPSS Logical Operators and Strings In a Simple Expression

Tags: if-statement, logical-operators, spss

I'm having some unexpected errors in achieving the following functionality. In this example code, I have the temperature on several days of the week. For this generalized example, I'm interested in determining the days that are 72,74, or 65 degrees. As an output, a variable should be created that contains the day of the week that is within this temperature range. Also, please note that in these data there is only ever 1 day that would fall within have one of these temperatures.

```
Monday     Tuesday     Wednesday     Day of Interest    
72         78          80            
61         78          74            



Monday     Tuesday     Wednesday     Day of Interest    
72         78          80             2  
61         78          74             4
```

I wrote the following code, with the generous help of the great folks here at StackOverflow,

```
IF (Monday = 65 OR 72 OR 74) Day_Of_Interest = 2.
IF (Tuesday= 65 OR 72 OR 74) Day_Of_Interest = 3.
IF (Wednesday = 65 OR '72' OR 74) Day_Of_Interest = 4.
IF (Thursday = 65 OR 72 OR 74) Day_Of_Interest = 5.
```

but sadly it returns an error:

```
 IF A relational operator may have two numeric operands or two character 
string operands. To compare a character string to a numeric quantity,
consider using the STRING or NUMBER function.'
```

I tried changing the code to be akin to '65' OR '72', but this produced another error. I would really appreciate if anyone had any thoughts on how to make this work. I know the example above isn't the best, but it's the best I could think of. If you need anymore details I'd be more than happy to oblige. Thanks so much for your help!

Edit: I should say that this code does work if I am just looking for one number, say 72.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `IF` with multiple comparisons will only work this way:

```
IF (Monday = 65 OR Monday = 72 OR Monday = 74) Day_Of_Interest = 2.
```

But in this situation `ANY` function will be more useful:

```
IF any(Monday, 65, 72, 74) Day_Of_Interest = 2.
```

Now if you want to do this for all weekdays, you can use a loop:

```
do repeat day=Sunday Monday Tuesday Wednesday Thursday Friday Saturday
    /Dnum=1 2 3 4 5 6 7.
    IF any(day, 65, 72, 74) Day_Of_Interest = Dnum.
end repeat.
exe.
```

Comment: Hey eli, that's a perfect answer. Thank you so much for your time and effort. Have a great day.